# Custom messages using RabbitMQ/ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, activemq-classic

I am coming from Sidekiq and am now moving to a Java solution for distributed jobs. I came across RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ, but it seems those brokers use plaintext or raw byte[] messages. I was wondering if it's possible to send custom messages using these frameworks?

Ideally I would just define a Java class for each specific message type and use that in both worker and producer. Is such a thing possible? Or should I look at other types of middleware?

```
 MyOwnMessageFormat message = new MyOwnMessageFormat(content)
 channel.send(message)

 Message message = channel.receive()
 if (message.class == MyOwnMessageFormat)
 {
      doSomething();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Exchanging messages through message brokers in Java is much easier when done through a service bus like Camel. You dont loose the flexibility of configuring your broker endpoint and still your code is isolated from the particular transport used or the message format. E.g. you can deploy ActiveMQ and later switch to RabbitMQ without having to update your code - just the service bus configuration. Or you can switch from plain Java serialization to JSON when sending messages to the broker by adding a message transformer. Again your business layer does not have to be modified.

Here's a sample that uses POJO producing/consuming where the producer calls a regular Java interface and the consumer implements the interface. The sample assumes that the sender/receiver are instantiated with Spring in order for the Camel endpoints to be injected

Message sender:

```
interface MyService {
   MyResult addTask(MyTask task);
}  

class Sender {
    @Produce(uri="activemq:queue:myservice")
    MyService service;

    public void run() {
      MyTask task = new MyTask();
      MyResult result = service.addTask(task);
}
```

Message receiver:

```
class Receiver {
    @Consume(uri="activemq:queue:myservice")
    public MyResult addTask(MyTask task) {
         return new MyResult();
    }
}
```

MyTask & MyResult need to be serializable.

I think learning the Camel framework is not very hard while it can be very rewarding.

Answer (score 1):

In JMS,as long as your custom message object is Serializable, you can use an ObjectMessage,Stream Message or Map Message according to your requirement like below to send(Object Message):

```
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer( destination );
ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage( getMyObject() );
producer.send( message );
```

For receiving:

```
 Message message = consumer.receive();
if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
Object object = ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Before publishing the message to RabbitMQ, convert your message to a Json String. 
Now on the receiving end, when the message is received, Parse it to convert into the same format.

In ruby this can be done with

while sending => Message.to_json 

on Receiving => message = JSON.parse(received_msg)

To get the class of data, you can send a variable specifying the class of the data along with the data.

Comment: Yes, that is sort of a solution, but I really dislike that. I prefer to just use java classes. But I could indeed write a general parser that returns the java objects I want based on the JSON.

Comment: Or you could use Jackson, spring amqp or any marshal/serilization abstraction layer you like.

Comment: Why do you supply code examples in ruby when the question is about java? Psuedo code is probably a better trade off than ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me with the latest version of ActiveMQ

```
...
MessageConsumer consumer=session.createConsumer(destination);       

while(true) {
    javax.jms.Message message=consumer.receive();
    ActiveMQObjectMessage queueMessage=(ActiveMQObjectMessage)message;
    Object payload=queueMessage.getObject();
    if(payload instanceof NotificationMessage) {
        this.sendMessage((NotificationMessage)payload);
    }
}
```

The `NotificationMessage` object extends `Serializable` and looks like this

```
public static class NotificationMessage implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1631373969001850200L;

    public String to;
    public String data;

}
```